# 0.01 difference in arithematic calculation followed by rounding to 2 decimal places in java

Tags: java, performance, currency

I am facing a new problem. Let's take a look at this piece of code:

```
private void calculate(double value) {
double arate = 10.75;
double brate = 18.0;
double crate = arate+brate;

double svalue = value /(1-(crate/100));
double tvalue = svalue*(brate/100);
double uvalue = svalue*(arate/100);
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

System.out.println(df.format(tvalue));
System.out.println(df.format(uvalue));
}
```

when I input value as 158.97 tvalue is 40.16, uvalue is 23.98
when I input value as 8.13 tvalue is 2.05, uvalue is 1.23
when I input value as 150.84,tvalue is 38.11, uvalue is 22.76

Here I expected uvalue to be equal to 22.75 because input is difference of first two values. I think the difference is due to rounding of values.
Is it possible to solve this? I tried by changing to BigDecimal and using different rounding but it is not helping.

Comment: double is error prone to rounding errors. You should use BigDecimal all over the place instead to avoid rounding errors.

Comment: If you only and always care about two decimals and your numbers' absolute values are < 2^7 (approximately), you may think about using integers two orders of magnitude bigger then your current numbers and then dividing them by 100.0 before outputting them.

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca thank you for your suggestion,I will try it

Comment: I am using this calculation for problem related to money. Is there any best practice for this type of problems?

Comment: @Simulant I tried changing to BigDecimal and using different scales and rounding strategy but it is giving me same result

Comment: please update your code to include the BigDecimal. Make sure that you use the String based constructor new BigDecimal("0.75"), otherwise the BigDecimal with be initialised with the inaccurate value of the double resulting in the same error.